# "Please be informed that we have sent back"

Tags: business-language

Is it correct to write:

> "Please be informed that we have sent back"

Comment: It feels as if there is something missing...

Comment: As the start of a sentence, it's correct but old fashioned. You could just say *We have sent it back*. "This is to inform you" is a legal signal that prevents you from the later complaint of *They never told me*.

Comment: Sent back what?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I assume this to be an extract from a bigger sentence that includes an object for the verb *sent*, such as "We have sent back the item that we received" or "We have sent back the purchase to the shop".

It is clear from the incomplete sentence that something has been returned to its previous place. There may have been other possibilities: "we have sent *the item to London*"; "we have sent *the item on to the next recipient*"; "we have sent *the tool for repair*"; "we have sent *it for inspection*". If these alternatives are to be excluded, it may be necessary and correct to say "*we have sent back *the item to its original place*".

Comment: I really appreciate it.. thank you..

Comment: I disagree.  The original sentence does not make sense on its own. It requires a direct object.   This is also true for the other examples, e.g. "We have sent on to the next recipient" is incorrect. It should be "we have sent [object] on to the next recipient"

Comment: @chasly - supports Monica If you reread my answer you will find that I had to assume it to be an extract from a sentence with an object, so it is not clear to me what you disagree with. Please clarify for the benefit of the questioner's understanding, if for nothing else. I have added a few ellipses to try to deal formally with your point.

Comment: @Anton - I understand what you are saying. I'm just doubtful that those fragments would fit into a natural sentence as they are. For example, "we have sent to London"  requires an extra word in the middle, e.g. "we have sent **it** to London or similar.  You can't really say, "We have sent to London **it**" or "**It**, we have sent to London.

Comment: I see that you have added ellipses since my last comment.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Yes, I am a bit slow today - trying to do three things at once! Thanks for your point; you are in truth correct and I relied too much on implication about an object. I hope between us that we have dealt with it all satisfactorily now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to write:
>
> "Please be informed that we have sent back"

No it is not correct. "to send back" is a transitive verb and requires a direct object.

Examples with a direct object added:

1. *Please be informed that we have sent **it** back*  ("it" refers to something that has already been mentioned in a previous sentence)

2a. "Please be informed that we have sent the **parcel/item/consignment** back"

or

2b. "Please be informed that we have sent back the **parcel/item/consignment**

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It is a correct answer. If you disagree please say why. Thank you.

Comment: Some users here feel that answering too-basic and un-researched questions deserves a DV...(not mine).

Comment: @Cascabel - Thanks, good point. I sometimes alternate rapidly between ELL and ELU and lose track of where i'm at. I'll try to be more discerning.

Comment: That said, I am wondering if there is not now a trend to answer question lacking in research which once we would have closed...